# Newton and the change of mass with time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, history

I always thought that $force$ is $mass * acceleration$. Well, that's what I learnt at school a while back. Now, I have been enlightened that force is in fact the rate of change of momentum.

What makes this interesting to me, is that this takes into account a change in mass with respect to time as also playing a role in the force. A nice example of this is that of a rocket taking off. But clearly, this was not an example that Newton had in mind.

So my question: What did Newton have in mind of something where the mass changes with time?

I appreciate that my question is similar to say: [How did Newton discover his second law?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/how-did-newton-discover-his-second-law) but I didn't read anywhere there about the concept of change of mass with time.

Comment: Duplicate question. See [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/113686/5739)  I'm not privy to Newton's thought process, but one thing is clear: the second law applies only to systems of constant mass.

Comment: @garyp So basically, what I learnt all those years ago, is quite correct. Who would have thought it! Many thanks for the link.