# Rocket equation vs $F = dP/dt$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rocket-science

Let's say a rocket is moving along $\hat{i}$ and is ejecting mass at a rate of $r$ with relative velocity $-k \hat{i}$ under constant external force $F$

The rocket equation,
$$m\frac{dv}{dt} = F + u\frac{dm}{dt}$$
gives me 
$$(m_0-rt)\frac{dv}{dt} = F + (-k)(-r)$$

However, using $F = dP/dt$ I get 
$$F = m_0\frac{dv}{dt} + vr$$
which gives me a different $v(t)$

I want to know why using 
$$F = \frac{dP}{dt} = m\frac{dv}{dt} + v\frac{dm}{dt}$$ is failing me.

I suspect that $F = dP/dt$ might be only valid for closed systems, but why?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Personally I can't follow much of what you've done here, some more description would likely help you.  Also, you should add your actual question _to the question_.

Comment: Newton's laws are valid only for constant mass systems.  That's simply an assumption made when transitioning from point-mass systems to systems made of multiple particles.   Otherwise, the equations of motion for extended systems would not resemble the point-mass equations of motion.  For more info, [see this SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/113686/5739)

Comment: @garyp Oh, I see. Using $F = dP/dt$ for an open system leads to an equation that is not Galilean invariant! So my suspicion that F = dP/dt being applicable to only closed systems is correct in that case. Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?