# Can the reference point in an inertial frame be accelerated when applying torque equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, torque

Torque about a point = rate of change of angular momentum about that point.

Say we're in an inertial frame and see a body accelerating and rotating and another point(either a part of this body or an external point) accelerating.

Can we apply T = dL/dt for that body about that accelerating point if we are in an inertial frame?

My guess is we can since angular momentum depends on the reference point.
Is there any requirement for this point to be non-accelerating?

Comment: Oh, that was a typo. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The law you state is only valid for the center of mass, or for a fixed point in space.

Euler' law of rotation states:

**Net torque of an object about the center of mass equals the rate of change of angular momentum measured at the center of mass**.

$$ \boldsymbol{T}_C = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} (\boldsymbol{L}_C) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} (\mathrm{I}_C \boldsymbol{\omega}) = \mathrm{I}_C \dot{\boldsymbol{\omega}} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{L}_C \tag{1} $$

where point *C* denotes the center of mass. This a direct equivalent to the fact that the net force on a body describes the motion of the center of mass only. The remaining motion (about the center of mass) is described by Euler's law.

The center of mass can be accelerating (and usually is) since usually both torque and force are considered at the same time

$$ \boldsymbol{F} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}( \boldsymbol{p} ) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}(m\, \boldsymbol{v}_C ) = m\, \dot{ \boldsymbol{v}}_C \tag{2} $$

So now what happens at a different location *A*? Consider the location vector $\boldsymbol{c}$ of the center of mass, relative to *A*

Angular momentum at *A* is

$$ \boldsymbol{L}_A = \boldsymbol{L}_C + \boldsymbol{c} \times \boldsymbol{p} \tag{3} $$

Net torque at *A* is

$$ \boldsymbol{T}_A = \boldsymbol{T}_C + \boldsymbol{c} \times \boldsymbol{F} \tag{4}  $$

The total derivative of angular momentum at *A* is

$$ \require{cancel}
\begin{aligned} \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} ( \boldsymbol{L}_A ) & = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} ( \boldsymbol{L}_C + \boldsymbol{c} \times \boldsymbol{p} ) =  \boldsymbol{T}_C + \frac{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{c}}{{\rm d}t} \times \boldsymbol{p} + \boldsymbol{c} \times \underbrace{ \frac{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{p}}{{\rm d}t}}_{\boldsymbol{F}} \\
& = \boldsymbol{T}_A + \underbrace{( \boldsymbol{v}_C  - \boldsymbol{v}_A ) \times \boldsymbol{p} }_{(\boldsymbol{v}_C-\boldsymbol{v}_A) \times (m\,\boldsymbol{v}_C) = -\boldsymbol{v}_A \times m\,\boldsymbol{v}_C = \boldsymbol{p} \times \boldsymbol{v}_A}
\end{aligned} \tag{5}$$

I produce the following law (if no one else claims it, call it the [ja72](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/392/ja72) law).

**The rate of change of angular momentum at a non-fixed arbitrary point *A* equals the net torque at *A*, plus cross product of linear momentum with the speed of *A*.**

$$ \boxed{
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} ( \boldsymbol{L}_A ) = \boldsymbol{T}_A + \boldsymbol{p} \times  \boldsymbol{v}_A   } \tag{6} $$

The conditions where the derivate of angular momentum is exactly the net torque at a point _A_on a rigid body are as follows:

1. Body undergoes pure rotation with zero linear momentum, $\boldsymbol{p}=0$
2. Point *A* is fixed in space, or instaneneously fixed, $\boldsymbol{v}_A=0$
3. Point *A* is on the center of mass, making its motion parallel to momentum, $\boldsymbol{v}_A \parallel \boldsymbol{p}$
4. Point *A* lies on a line parallel to the rotation axis, but through the center of mass, $\boldsymbol{v}_A \parallel \boldsymbol{v}_C$

Comment: In the original derivation of Torque = dL/dt, nowhere did we use that assumption. https://phys.libretexts.org/TextMaps/Classical_Mechanics_TextMaps/Map%3A_Classical_Mechanics_(Tatum)/3%3A_Systems_of_Particles/3.11%3A_Torque_and_Rate_of_Change_of_Angular_Momentum

Comment: @xasthor - Isn't the correct form of the time derivative $$\dot{\bf L} = \sum_i ( \dot{\bf r}_{i}\times {\bf p}_{i}+{\bf r}_{i}\times \dot{\bf p}_{i})$$ The cross product is linear operator and the regular product rule applies for derivatives.

Comment: @xasthor - also what is ${\bf F}_{i}$ and ${\bf F}_{ij}$ that their sum equals velocity?

Comment: @xasthor - Euler's laws of rotation motion apply at the center of mass only. You cannot pick an arbitrary location for the net torque since a body rotates only if the line of action of a force is not at the center of mass. Also, angular momentum _not at the center of mass_ includes the moment of momentum component which is a function of linear motion. See [The derivation of Equations of Motion _not at the center of mass_](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80449/392) to see why $\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} ( \boldsymbol{L}_A ) \neq \boldsymbol{T}_A$ at any point _A_.

Comment: derivative of $r_i$ is $v_i$ which when crossed with $p_i$ =0 since they are in the same direction. hence the sum simplifies into the summation of torques. nothing about that sum specifies that L or T is about the center of mass. it seems to be about any arbitrarily point

Comment: @xasthor I understand that part, and I have it in my answer also as $v_C \times p = 0$, but there are other terms that are not zero that are missing from TextMaps. Can you please explain how $\dot{\bf r}_{i} = {\bf F}_{i} + \sum {\bf F}_{ij}$ works? How is velocity equals the sum of forces? The center of mass is implied to be at the origin in that post.

Comment: yeah that equation doesn't make sense. I didn't read it carefully before posting it, sorry. check this one out https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://web.mit.edu/8.01t/www/materials/modules/chapter19.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiUtq___oLaAhXGqo8KHZPNAaAQFjABegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw37oyAtBsy3VBsac-GfIvtX page 13. Here, I quote Daniel Kleppner: "The external torque about point S is equal to the time derivative of the angular momentum of the system about that point"

Comment: While I read this, can you look at [this related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/391862/392) which establishes total linear and angular momentum for a system of particles. This would be the basis used to show that torque and angular momentum rate only equate each other at the center of mass, or at a fixed point or if the center of mass is fixed. In the system of particles models, the measurement point for angular momentum is fixed (the origin) and so with $v_A=0$ then $ \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} ( \boldsymbol{L}_A ) = \boldsymbol{T}_A $

Comment: @xasthor - For a point (as in a single point) yes it is true because the velocity is parallel to momentum. For for a system of particles (like a rigid body) with any sort of rotation, momentum is not parallel to the velocity of any arbitrary point.

Comment: Daniel Kleppner proved it for a rigid body at page 13 of that document

Comment: @xasthor - Point _S_ is fixed in space at page 13. You can see that is implied between equations `(19.5.3)` and `(19.5.4)`. If you try to go through the same proof with a point _S_ riding on the body and you get my law. The difference is that the location of each point _j_ is $r_j = r_S + r_{j,S}$ so in `(19.5.4)` $\frac{{\rm d}\vec{r}_j}{{\rm d}t} = \vec{v}_S + \vec{v}_{j,S}$  or $$ \frac{{\rm d}\vec{r}_j}{{\rm d}t} \times \vec{p}_j = \vec{v}_S \times \vec{p}_j \neq 0$$ I have added in my answer the conditions which would make the above zero.

Comment: @xasthor - Take a free rolling wheel and calculate the angular momentum of a point on the rim. Put a coordinate system on the contact point and trace the point around. Now find if angular momentum about that point is conserved. It is not. But the net torque about the point is always zero.

Comment: @xasthor Hello. Sorry for bothering you, but I don't understand how the equation 3.11.3 in the link you posted holds true.

Comment: This post shows tthat a wrong concept leads to a wrong conclusion. In Newtonian mechanics, the relation $\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = \vec{\tau}$ is valid for all inertial frame. The conclusion here breaks this eqivalent principle of Newtonian mechnics.

Comment: The wrong concepts are that (1) the author believe that the relation between angular momentum and torque is only valid in the COM frame; (2) the author believes that the momentum of a rigid body is alway equal to the momentum measured at the point of COM, which is not true, against the basic definition of momentum.

Comment: Deailed explanation please see the answer I post below.

Comment: @ytlu [Pages 9-10 of this lecture](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~meam535/cgi-bin/pmwiki/uploads/Main/Newton_Euler_11.pdf) establishes equation (1) above. Agree on the relationship between and. momentum and torque _at the center of mass_ of a rigid body and at the origin of an inertial frame?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou The page 9 and 10 concluded that the rate change of angular momentum is equal to torque for both origin O and ortigin C. I don't undertand you points.

Comment: I agree with this point since both points would make my extra term zero. I have a more [detailed presentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iEHGoGUC-eBHuutSqVmzNulGMq8FGUTF/view?usp=sharing) of my argument of why my equation is correct **including an example** that produces the correct result with my equation and an incorrect result with your equation. All in the context of a single rigid body in motion as viewed by a single _inertial_ observer.

Comment: @ytlu - The [same paper](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ja72/101c8eb741fd53cbdf61d35646484602/raw/a71ffa324286c96dcf6eb8f3052f414ab7b4ae46/index.html) as the comment above but published in HTML instead of PDF.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou It is the same stuff. There are nothing to make your saying right. Peoriod. Wrong cannot be right.

Comment: @ytlu - did you see in the end the example. With the "extra" terms it yields the incorrect solution. After a careful re-examination of everything, I stand by my posts. Remember, I am talking about **a single reference frame** observing multiple points, and in the examples you mention you are talking about two reference frames. I am talking about one frame.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou "talking about a single reference frame observing multiple points", this nonsense saying. A observe point is a coordinate frame. Beside that there are no observe points. This is a very basuc concept of physics.

Comment: @ytlu - In physics, the location of the observer is the coordinate frame. Where the observer is looking is an observation point. The coordinate frame defines the basis vectors and the origin where distances are measured _to observation points_. This is fundamental to physics. 

In my scenario. I am standing on the ground holding a long stick pointing at different locations in space. I am looking at the center of mass **C** or some other arbitrary point **A** _observing_ what is happening at that location.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou When you write $\mathbf{L}_A$, it means that a angular momentum measured at the Frame A (even though it is a point without a cross attached to it). This is without ambiguity. The definition is position vector measure from A $\times$ velocity measure from  A.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I don't even know how to name your quantity: position vector measured from A $\times$ velocity measure from O. It could be anything but $\mathbf{L}_A$.

Comment: @ytlu - $\boldsymbol{L}_A$ is the angular momentum if the body was rotating about **A** it is exactly defined as $$\boldsymbol{L}_A = \sum_i \boldsymbol{r}_i \times m_i \boldsymbol{v}_i$$ where $\boldsymbol{r}_i$ is the location of the particle w.r.t. point **A**. It is related to the angular momentum about the center of mass 
 $\boldsymbol{L}_C$ with the relationship you are disputing $$\boldsymbol{L}_A = \boldsymbol{L}_C + \boldsymbol{r}_{AC} \times \boldsymbol{p}$$ This is found also in literature like [equation 19.5.19 here](https://www.lehman.edu/faculty/anchordoqui/chapter19.pdf).

Comment: Your mistake is not on the position, but the velocity. Your $v_i$ is NOT the velocity measured from A. Therefore, your $L_A$ is not the angular momentum measured from A.

Comment: In my comment above I made a simplification that is confusing things. The definition of $L_A$ is based on $r_i$ the location of the particle relative to observer, and $v_i$ the velocity of the particle (from the observers point of view) as follows $$ \boldsymbol{L}_A = \sum_i (\boldsymbol{r}_i-\boldsymbol{r}_A) \times m_i \boldsymbol{v}_i $$ and now the velocity is clearly just $\boldsymbol{v}_i = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{r}_i$

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. I post to clarify the mistakes in the answer from John.

Now, lets forcus on your above answer. I show your clearly the errors.

Eq.  (3) in  this post:

[image: Eq.(3) in John's post]
Eq.(3) in John's post.

Where your defined $\mathbf{c}$ as : *Consider the location vector c of the center of mass, relative to A*. The point A has a velocity $\mathbf{v}_A$ refering to the origin O. And $\mathbf{p} = m \mathbf{v}_C$ is the velocity of the center of mass measured in frame O.

With these definitions, your Eq.(3) is **NOT** correct. Because A is moving with velocity  $\mathbf{v}_A$, therefore, in frame A, the total linear momentum of the rigid body is $m (\mathbf{v}_C - \mathbf{v}_A)$. This error led you into wrong conclusion in Eq.(5) and Eq. (6).

Since $\mathbf{v}_C$ and $\mathbf{p}$ is measured in frame O and $\mathbf{c}$ is measured in frame A. The Eq. (3) should written as:

$$
 \mathbf{L}_A = \mathbf{L}_C + \mathbf{c} \times m\left(\mathbf{v}_C - \mathbf{v}_A \right)
$$

With all quanties measured in frame A. This will correct your results in Eq.(5) and Eq.(6), reders $\frac{d\mathbf{L}_A}{dt} = \mathbf{\tau}_A$.

---

Following John, I change few notations:

- C : the center of mass frame
- $\vec{R}$ : the position of center of mass w.r.t. frame A ($\vec{c}$ of John.)
- frame A : another inertial frame, which has a relative constant velocity w.r.t C-frame.
- $\vec{v}_A$ : velocity of the point measured in frame A.
- $\vec{v}_C$ : velocity of the point measured in frame C.
- $\vec{r}_A$ : position of the point measure in frame A.
- $\vec{r}_C$ : position of the point measure in frame C.

The relation of positions:

$$ \tag{1}
 \vec{r}_A = \vec{R} + \vec{r}_C.
$$

Derive Eq.(1) leads to the relation in velocity:
$$ \tag{2}
 \vec{v}_A = \vec{V} + \vec{v}_C.
$$
where $\vec{V}$ is the velocity of COM in frame A. It must be a constant for both frames to be inertial.

The definition of the angular momentums:

$$
 \vec{L}_A = m \vec{r}_A \times \vec{v}_A\\
 \vec{L}_C = m \vec{r}_C \times \vec{v}_C\\
$$

Their relation can be found from Eq.(1) and Eq.(2):
$$
 \vec{L}_A = m \left(\vec{R} + \vec{r}_C \right) \times \left( \vec{V} + \vec{v}_C \right)\\
= m \left(\vec{R} + \vec{r}_C \right) \times \vec{V} + m \vec{R} \times \vec{v}_C + m \vec{r}_C \times \vec{v}_C\\
= \left\{ \vec{L}_C + m \vec{R} \times \vec{v}_C \right\} + m \left(\vec{R} + \vec{r}_C \right) \times \vec{V}\\
= \{ \text{John's term} \} + \{ \text{missed term.} \}
$$

The term inside the curry braket is show in John's equation. The last term is missed from his angular momentum relation. It is indeed $m \vec{r}_A  \times \vec{V}$, the extra agular momentum of the particle in the frame A due to relative motion between frame A and C.

The incorrect relation in angular momentum leads to his wrong conclusion. **His conclusion is a very serious accusation against the equivalent principle of all inertial frames - a very imprortant base concept of Newtonian mechanics**.

$$
 \frac{d\vec{L}_A}{dt} = m \frac{d\vec{r}_A}{dt} \times \vec{v}_A + m \vec{r}_A \times \frac{d\vec{v}_A}{dt}\\
 = 0 + m \vec{r}_A \times \frac{d\vec{v}_A}{dt}\\
=  m \vec{r}_A \times \frac{d}{dt} ( \vec{V} + \vec{v}_C )\\
=  \vec{r}_A \times \frac{d ( m \vec{v}_C ) }{dt}\\
=  \vec{r}_A \times \vec{F} = \vec{\tau}_A.
$$

As long as the relative motion is a constant velocity $\frac{d\vec{V}}{dt} = 0$, the rate change of angular momentum is equal to torque.

Describe a many-bodys motion in a certain inertial frame:

$$
  \vec{L}_{total} = \sum_i m_i \vec{r}_i \times \vec{v}_i\\
$$

And the rate change:
$$
 \frac{d\vec{L}_{total}}{dt} = \sum_i m_i \frac{d\vec{r}_i}{dt} \times \vec{v}_i + \sum_i  \vec{r}_i \times \frac{d \vec{p}_i}{dt}\\
 = \sum_i m_i 0 + \sum_i  \vec{r}_i \times \vec{F}_i\\
=  \sum_i  \vec{\tau}_i = \vec{\tau}_{total}
$$

If you try to argue that away from frame of center of mass:

$$
 \frac{d\vec{r}_i}{dt} \times \vec{v}_i \ne 0.
$$

You have to do much better that a hand-wave saying.

I will illustrate wuth a simple example, a dumbell of two point mass points ($2kg$) separate by massless wire (2m). Its center mass is moving with velocity
$\vec{V} = 4 m/s \vec{x} + 3 m/s \vec{y}$. In the center mass frame C, they rotate around the center with a frequency $\nu = 1/s$.

[image: Moving and rotation of a dumbbell.]

Describe the motion of these two masses in the center of mass (C frame) $\vec{r}_{Ci} = (x_i', y_i')$ for $i = 1, 2$:

$$
\begin{matrix}
  x_1' = \cos(2\pi t); & y_1'= \sin(2\pi t) \\
  x_2' = -\cos(2\pi t); & y_2'= -\sin(2\pi t) \\
  \text{Velocity:} & \\
  v_{1x}' = -2\pi \sin(2\pi t); & v_{1y}'= 2\pi\cos(2\pi t) \\
  v_{2x}' = 2\pi\sin(2\pi t); & v_{2y}'= -2\pi\cos(2\pi t) \\
\end{matrix}
$$

The angularmomentum in C $L_c = (0, 0, L_z') = (0, 0, L_{1z}'+L_{2z}')$:
$$
L_{1z}' =2 x_1' v_{1y}' -2 y_1' v_{1x}' = \cos(2\pi t)  4\pi\cos(2\pi t) - \sin(2\pi t) \{-4\pi \sin(2\pi t)\} = 4\pi.\\
L_{2z}' = 4\pi, \text{ similarly}\\
$$
The total angular momentum in fram C is $8\pi$, a constant in time.

Now, examine the angular momentum observed in Frame A, $\vec{r}_{iA} = (x_i, y_i)$, and the position of CM in frame A $\vec{R} = (4 t, 3 t)$:
$$
\begin{matrix}
  x_1 = 4 t + \cos(2\pi t); & y_1 = 3 t + \sin(2\pi t) \\
  x_2 = 4 t -\cos(2\pi t); & y_2 = 3 t - \sin(2\pi t) \\
  \text{Velocity:} & \\
  v_{1x} = 4 - 2\pi \sin(2\pi t); & v_{1y}=3 + 2\pi\cos(2\pi t) \\
  v_{2x} = 4 + 2\pi\sin(2\pi t); & v_{2y}= 3- 2\pi\cos(2\pi t) \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Now, check the angular momentum in frame A:
$$
\begin{matrix}
  L_{1z} = 2 \{ 4 t + \cos(2\pi t) \} \{3 + 2\pi\cos(2\pi t)\} - 2 \{3 t + \sin(2\pi t)\} \{4 - 2\pi \sin(2\pi t)\} \\
=4\pi + 6 \cos(2\pi t) + 16 t \pi\cos(2\pi t) - 8\sin(2\pi t) + 12 t\pi \sin(2\pi t).\\
  L_{2z} = 2\{ 4 t - \cos(2\pi t) \} \{3 - 2\pi\cos(2\pi t)\} -2\{3 t - \sin(2\pi t)\} \{4 + 2\pi \sin(2\pi t)\} \\
=4\pi - 6 \cos(2\pi t) - 16 t \pi\cos(2\pi t) + 8 \sin(2\pi t) - 12 t\pi \sin(2\pi t).\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Finally, the resultant angular momentum in Frame A:

$$
 L_{Az} = L_{1z} + L_{2z} = 8 \pi.
$$

It is also a constant in time, even though frame A has relative motion with Frame C.

Check John's identity for mass 1:

$$
\vec{R} \times m\vec{v}_1' = \hat{z} \{ 16 t\pi\cos(2\pi t) + 12 t\pi \sin(2\pi t)\}\\
L_{1z}' + [\vec{R} \times m\vec{v}_1']_z = 4\pi +  16 t\pi\cos(2\pi t) + 12 t\pi \sin(2\pi t) \ne L_{1z}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I am reviewing now, and I see there are some subtle differences in interpretation. For example $\vec{v}_C$ and $\vec{v}_A$ for is the velocity of a rigid body of whatever particle is at locations **C** and  **A** respectively, both measured from the same inertial frame (the world frame).

Comment: Where  i show only for one particle. Description of many particles will add a sum over all particles. Each of them has similar form in momentum relation between two frames.

Comment: I added a simple example continuing in my post, All qantity can be check in the simple model.

Comment: Can you please [review this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/445685/392) and see if you agree, This is the foundation on which I am building my rebuttal. The argument from the particle summation point of view. Also [this similar post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/570734/392) and goes into Newton;s laws also.

Comment: In the first post, I cannot find the subjects relatied to your angular momentum relation which was wrong.

Comment: Also, in the second post, there provided no derivation of the relation $L_a -= L_c + c \times p$. Can you make your argument straight by pointing out the reason why this equation is valid?

Comment: Like a commented elsewhere, [read this publication](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iEHGoGUC-eBHuutSqVmzNulGMq8FGUTF/view?usp=sharing) which expands in excruciating details why the above and my equations are still valid. I think our disagreement is in the interpretation of what each term means exactly, and this is why I have a lot of details included in this paper.

Comment: I added my comment on one of your previous post in the beginning of this post. Your post obviously had similar error in the angular momentum transfromation. You didn't keep a clear  notation system, and mixed physical quantities of different frame within a equation without proper correction.

Comment: In the publication you linked, the Eq(3) and Eq.(4) the $\omega$ should be different. The $\omega$ in Eq.(3) is the angular velocity of rigit boday rotating about the center of mass, and in Eq.(4) the $\omega$ is the rotation of COM around the point A. They are not general a same $\omega$. and again, in Eq.(9)  same eorror appeared. The angular mmentum in A is $L_A = \sum_i m_i (r_i - r_a) \times (v_i - v_a) $. This is your instrinsic error.

Answer (score 0):

If the body is in un-constrained motion, using the center of mass (CM) as the reference point, the sum of the torques from the real forces equals the change in the angular momentum, even if the CM is accelerating.  If the body is constrained to rotate about a point other than the CM and that point is accelerating, then fictictious forces/torques must be considered using that point as the reference point.  This is discussed at some length in the text Mechanics, by Symon.