# Derivation of Newton's Second Law of Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

How does one derive the equation that $F=Δp/Δt$ without using $F=ma$?
I reviewed [Deriving $F = ma$ - Newton's Second Law of Motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105460/), but it just assumed $F=Δp/Δt$.

Comment: Infinitesimal time form $F=ma$ is derived from its discrete form $F=Δp/Δt$ and not the other way round. It is axiomatically stated as a Law by Newton in the earliest times of calculus development  defining infinitesimals of time and velocity .

Answer (score 9):

> How does one derive the equation that F=Δp/Δt...

You can't derive it, it is a postulate of Newtonian mechanics. It is proven by comparison to experimental results.

The other form of the second law you wrote ($\vec F = m\vec a$) can be obtained from the basic postulate $\vec F = \frac{d\vec p}{dt}$ when the mass is constant.

---

**Update, to expand a bit more:**

The above answer is pithy, but I think it is an appropriate answer to the question at the level of an introductory high-school or college mechanics/physics course.

Of course, Newton did not write his second law in the same way, nor did he arrive at his second law by divine inspiration (as we seem to have). But rather he conducted, and observed, and knew of, various mechanics experiments such as: (1) a single small particle moving near the surface of the earth under earth's gravity (in approximate vacuum or in air); (2) two small masses connected by a relatively inextensible string also moving under earth's gravity; (3) observations of the motion of the planets and other astronomical bodies; (4) etc.

Based on the results of such experiments, we don't usually jump right to *momentum*, but rather start off by considering *acceleration*, which is defined as the second time derivative of position, as well as *mass*, which is defined below and is fixed/unchanging in the above-mentioned observations/experiments.

A general statement in English that summarizes and generalizes the above-mentioned observations/experiments can be found in Whittaker's mechanics textbook:

> "If any set of mutually connected particles are in motion, the acceleration with which any one particle moves is the resultant of the acceleration with which it would move if perfectly free, and accelerations directed along the lines joining it to the other particles which constrain its motion. Moreover, to the several particles A, B, C, ..., numbers $m_A$, $m_B$, $m_C$, ... can be assigned, such that the acceleration along AB due to the influence of B on A is to the acceleration along BA due to the influence of A on B in the ratio $m_B$:$m_A$. The ratios of these numbers $m_A$, $m_B$, ... are invariable physical constants of the particles."

The above statement, together with the definition of a "unit mass" (e.g., a kilogram weight), provides the working definition of mass.

Clearly, when the masses are fixed (and given the definition of momentum $\vec p = m \vec v$, where $\vec v$ is the first time derivative of the position), the two forms of Newton's second law ($F=ma$ and $F=dp/dt$) are equivalent.

Comment: I do not agree with this answer. Within the context of Newtonian mechanics, the mass of a body is immutable.  The only way it can change is if you alter the definition of what constitutes the "body".  If you do this (say by defining fuel as part of a rocket only until it's ejected), then your equation (1) is still wrong, or at least very misleading, because it doesn't deal with the velocity, after separation, of the parts of the body you've decided to exclude, or--in the case of increasing mass--with the velocity, before merging, of the parts you've decided to add on.

Comment: "Within the context of Newtonian mechanics, the mass of a body is immutable." Why? Why can't I propose an example/toy problem where, say, $m(t) = m_0 + \alpha t$. E.g., a truck driving in the snow that accumulates mass as snow falls on it.

Comment: Of course you can do such.  Then you must tell how fast the snow is moving the instant before it becomes part of the truck.  Or else you will get the wrong answer.

Comment: Check out the first answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53980/) which I just found.  It explains the error better than I have here.

Comment: Sure, you would have to know the rate that the mass changes due to snowfall (in the example problem I gave, that rate is an arbitrary constant in the problem statement I called $\alpha$). But, if I were asked, say: "assuming there is no net horizontal force on the truck, how long does it take for the truck's velocity to decrease to half its initial velocity?" I could use Newtonian mechanics to solve this problem.

Comment: No. You cannot say that a truck is moving at variable speed through falling snow and experiences no net horizontal force.  Unless the horizontal velocity of the snow somehow always magically matches that of the truck, you have contradicted physics in the statement of the question.

Comment: Ok, so then also assume that the horizontal velocity of the snow always magically matches that of the truck. It's my toy problem, I can change it however I like, can't I? In this case: $\alpha \dot x = -(m_0 + \alpha t)\ddot x$, which I can solve.

Comment: But, anyways, I removed the final offending paragraph.

Comment: But it is wrong.  If the snow always matches the horizontal speed of the truck, it never slows down at all.  Equation (1) is just not right.  Did you check out the question I linked?

Comment: Yes, I did look at the question you linked.

Comment: @Ben51 obviously in Newtonian mechanics a closed system has conserved mass, but a non-closed one does not need to do so, and we are under no compulsion to only consider closed systems. It's perfectly licit to model the snow truck as accumulating a mass of snow (at a rate proportional to its speed). The usual derivation of the rocket equation does a similar thing under time reversal

Comment: "small single particle" == "apple"?

Comment: *"apocryphal apple"

Answer (score 8):

Depends the framework in which you are working, in other words, in your system of axioms and your definitions. To give an example from pure Mathematics, in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$ a compact set can be defined as a subset which is closed and bounded or either as a subset with the property that any open cover admits a finite subcover. Now if you decide to *define* a compact set as one which is closed and bounded, then you can *prove* that any open cover has a finite subcover. Otherwise, if you decide to *define* a compact set by means of open coverings you can then *prove* that it is closed and bounded.

This is sort of what is going on here. In Newtonian Mechanics, Newton's second law is one *axiom* of the theory. So it is something you assume to be true and derive results from it. Since we are talking about Physics, these results are then later compared to experiment thereby validatings several tests of that underlying basic axiom.

But this need not be the case. Indeed you could work in another framework in which you can actually derive Newton's second law. To give a concrete example of what I mean, in Lagrangian Mechanics the basic axiom is another one. It is the variational principle which states that the path of evolution of a system is the one which extremizes the action $$S=\int_{a}^b L(q(t),\dot q(t),t)dt.\tag{1}$$

Here the evolution of the configuration of the system in time is described by one or more *generalized coordinates* $q(t)$ and the associated derivatives $\dot{q}(t)$. The equations of motion that follow from the variational principle are the Euler-Lagrange equations $$\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial q}\tag{2}.$$

If one then *defines* the *generalized force* $F$ and the *generalized momentum* $p$ by the equations $$F\equiv \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial q},\quad p\equiv \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\tag{3}$$
then the Euler-Lagrange equation reads $$F=\dfrac{dp}{dt}\tag{4}.$$

In other words, in the framework of Lagrangian Mechanics, with suitable definitions of force and momentum, the Euler-Lagrange equation takes the form of Newton's second law.

In particular, in this theoretical framework the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation from the action by means of the variational principle is a derivation of Newton's second law.

So in conclusion your answer depends on the framework you are working on. In Newtonian Mechanics there is no derivation since it is one basic axiom. In other frameworks like Lagrangian Mechanics you may derive it from whatever other basic axiom is in place.

Comment: Well, the consensus on Phys.SE seems to be that answers can target a more general audience, so that people with other background might benefit. Nevertheless, while I have ilustrated with a concrete example from pure Math and concrete formulae from Lagrangian Mechanics, the OP does not need to understand any of the inner workings of these to appreciate the central message of the answer: what he asks is framework dependent and for a specific choice of framework won't be something amenable to derivation and for others it will.

Comment: How do you define lagrangian at first place in form of kinetic and potential energy. Newton's second law is axiomatic and which came from definition of inertia or state of motion.

Comment: I suppose the idea is that you can define the "ma" quantity and Force independently and derive Kinetic and Potential Energy to write down Lagrangian. The conclusion of optimizing Lagrangian would be that F=ma / two concepts are numerically equal @NeilLibertine

Answer (score 2):

The expression $$ \boldsymbol{F} = \tfrac{ {\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{p} $$

is the definition for momentum $\boldsymbol{p}$.

Momentum is the result of a net force $\boldsymbol{F}$ acting over a finite time

$$ \Delta \boldsymbol{p} = \int_{\Delta t} \boldsymbol{F}\,{\rm d}t $$

Momentum is *measured* with $\boldsymbol{p}=m \boldsymbol{v}$, but it is not defined by it. Momentum is the result of a force acting over time.

This means that if you assume a constant force $\boldsymbol{F}$ over a time period $\Delta t$ then

$$ 
\Delta \boldsymbol{p} = m \Delta \boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{F} \Delta t 
$$

or

$$ \boldsymbol{F} = \frac{ \Delta \boldsymbol{p}}{\Delta t} = m \frac{ \Delta \boldsymbol{v}}{ \Delta t} $$

and for an infinitesimal time frame

$$ \boldsymbol{F} = \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{p} = m \boldsymbol{a} $$

Comment: Might add if memory serves.. F*dt = m*dv (in words of my physics teacher "Kraftstoß=Impuls" ~ power surge equals impulse) which leads directly to F=m*dv/dt => F=m*a

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer in general. Not every law of Physics is "derivable". It's not pure math. In mathematics you have a set of axioms and then derive some conclusions from it. In Physics, derivations have no added value, unless it helps to build a new theory. Instead, added value is in verification of laws, principles, assumptions and what not, in experimental or observational ways.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified what we are supposed to take as axioms in deriving this equation. One possibility is the following. Suppose a particle is moving in a one-dimensional potential $V(x)$. We assume that the particle obeys the conservation of energy, given as
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(x)\right)=0,
$$
where we define momentum as
$$
p = m\frac{dx}{dt}.
$$
We also define the force as
$$
F=-\frac{dV}{dx}.
$$
Then differentiating the energy conservation equation gives
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(x)\right)=\frac{p}{m}\frac{dp}{dt} + \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dV}{dx}=0
$$
Then using the definition of momentum and the definition of force, we have
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dp}{dt} - \frac{dx}{dt}F=0.
$$
Whenever $dx/dt\neq 0$, it follows that
$$
\frac{dp}{dt}=F.
$$
However, conservation of energy alone is not sufficient to prove the statement when $dx/dt=0$.